# Is "adeptus astra telepathica" grammatically correct?

Tags: vocabulary, grammar-choice

In the multimedia franchise Warhammer 40,000, a space empire known as the Imperium of Man [uses various Latin phrases](http://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Imperium#Imperial_Organisations) to name their various government departments. I looked these up in Latin translators and most seem to be untranslatable gibberish.

Such phrases include Astra Militarum ("imperial guard"), Questor Imperialis ("imperial knights"), Adepta Sororitas ("sisters of battle"), Adeptus Custodes, Militarum Tempestus ("imperial stormtroopers"), Adeptus Astartes ("space marines"), Adeptus Ministorum, Adeptus Mechanicus, Adeptus Astra Telepathica, and Scholastica Psykana.

This is supposed to simulate how "High Gothic" (a fictitious dead language used for commerce) sounds to citizens of the Imperium, which to us sounds like bad Latin and the phrases seem to be derived from misspelled Latin or by loaning foreign words (as is often done in New Latin). "Adeptus" appears in many such names, as in "Adeptus Astartes" that seems to be derived from the Latin *aster*. I got the impression that the names are supposed to mean "Adept of [insert task]" though this never appears in the English names.

Where an etymological origin may be discerned (often grammatically nonsensical, if I understand the inflection correctly), the official English name is often completely unrelated in meaning. "Imperial guard" versus *astra mīlitārium* ("the stars the military"), "imperial knight" versus *quaestor imperiālis* ("the questor imperial")," "sisters of battle" versus *adepta sorōritās* ("the obtained the sisterhood"), "imperial stormtrooper" versus *mīlitārium tempestās* ("the military the weather"), "space marines" versus *adeptus astertās* ("the obtained the stardom"), etc.

What is the correct form of such phrases in Latin?

Comment: Warhammer games are the purest fantasy, and that also applies to the cod Latin terms that they use. You are right to call them untranslatable gibberish, and I commend the moderation of your language in doing so!

Comment: @TomCotton: IIRC, Games Workshop devises this gibberish because it may be trademarked, whereas Latin phrases may not.

Comment: Interesting, I had assumed that Adeptus Astartes had something to do with the goddess [Astarte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astarte) (Ishtar). Astartes would be a genitive singular form of her name.

Comment: @cnread: Since "adeptus astartes" is supposedly Canis Latinicus for "space marine," then "astartes" should be related to the Latin "aster." Adding the suffix "[-tas](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-tas)" is the only way it would have that form. Then somehow the last two vowels were transposed by mistake?

Answer (score 2):

[Tom Cotton](https://latin.stackexchange.com/users/645/tom-cotton) is right in saying that all of the provided "Latin phrases" are nothing but gibberish. However, since you asked for the "correct forms" of the provided phrases (that had corresponding English "translations"), I've written them here to the best of my ability:

- "Imperial Guard": *custōs imperiālis*
- "Imperial Knight": *eques imperiālis*
- "Sisters of Battle": *sorōrēs proeliī*
- "Imperial Soldier": *mīles imperiālis*
- "Space Marine": *mīles asterum* (technically means "soldier of the stars", but it's probably as close as you can get to "Space Marine")

As for whether the single phrase "adeptus astra telepathica" is correct (as you asked in the title of your question): it's not. *adeptus* doesn't match the number or gender of *astra*, and "telepathica" isn't even a Latin word, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Why nominative *astēr* instead of genitive for Space Marine?

Comment: Also, while *telepathica* isn't native Latin, it's fairly transparently from Greek *tēl-* + *path-* + *-icos*; I'd think an educated Roman would recognize it as meaning "distant-emotion-having" (i.e. telepathic).

Comment: (That said, good answer; +1)

Comment: @Draconis Thanks, and good to know regarding *telepathica*. As for why I chose the nominative over the genitive in *astēr mīles*; I just felt that it matched the English noun phrase "space marine" better than something that would've translated as "soldier of the stars" or "marine of space". I suppose it's just a matter of personal opinion there. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @EthanBierlein: IIRC English places adjectives before nouns, whereas Latin places adjectives after nouns. So would "astēr mīles" not mean "star of the military" instead?

Comment: @Draconis: If I understand grammar correctly then the correct form would be *adeptum astrī tēlepāthicī* or "adept of the star telepathic", I think? I honestly have no idea how you would translate the intended meaning "adept of astrotelepathy."

Comment: @Anonymous Firstly: *adeptus, -a, -um* means *overtaken* or *obtained*, not "adept", despite the similar appearance. A better adjective would be something like *perītus, -a, -um*, which means "skilled" or "skillful".

Comment: @Anonymous Secondly: a better way of phrasing what is trying to be said would probably be "[he is] adept/skilled *with* astrotelepathy", which would roughly translate as *[is est] perītus cum astrō tēlepāthicō*.

Comment: @EthanBierlein: your statement that the suitability of astēr mīles vs. something else is 'just a matter of personal opinion' isn't correct. In Latin, unlike English, you can't just stick two nouns in the same case together like this to form a compound noun phrase. Astēr mīles wouldn't literally mean 'star soldier,' as you claim: it would mean 'a star (and) a soldier.' 'Space marine' would have to be phrased as 'marine of space/the stars,' using either a noun in, e.g., the genitive (e.g., asterum/astrorum -- probably should be plural rather than singular) or an adjective (e.g., stellaris).

Comment: @cnread Noted. Will update answer.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I got the impression that "imperial guard" is supposed to mean a group of people (cf. pretorian guard) as opposed to a single guard person. In that case I might suggest *cohors* instead of *custos*.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Could be a possibility. When I was translating, however, I made the assumption that each of the names was referring to a role a single person could hold. I could easily be wrong though.

Comment: @EthanBierlein: The names are for organizations and government departments, not specific individual roles. Though they are often used that way too.